# I have issue in bootsrap class, its display properly in normal screen but issue in mobile size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row padding5px">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <span class="login-block-header" id="lblAccountHeading">Account Number</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="ddlAccountNo" class="form-control">
      <option>Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="btnReport" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show Report</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have issue in bootstrap. I have added classes to control the widths, and they display in one row on a normal screen but re-sizing on a mobile doesn't display correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the correct bootstrap column size tags, `col-xs-` for mobile devices, along with the ones for a larger screen. So you can say `class="col-md-2 col-xs-3"` for example.

So your HTML might look like this;

```
<div class="row padding5px">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
    <span class="login-block-header" id="lblAccountHeading">Account Number</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5">
    <select id="ddlAccountNo" class="form-control">
      <option>Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5">
    <button id="btnReport" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show Report</button>
  </div>
</div>
```